# MultiValueDictKeyError Django Google App Engine - Multiple File Upload?

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I would like to know how to fix the error below `'MultiValueDictKeyError'`:
It happens when uploading 5 big image files. And it happens only sometimes. Depending on the size of the image files. Eg: It works sometimes with small image files.

**HTML FORM**

```
        <form enctype="multipart/form-data" action="/gallery/new/" method="post">

            <input type='hidden' name='csrfmiddlewaretoken' value='2G9xCcnqFP47Z1c9RelOamnzv8g5l7pT' />
            <p><label for="id_name">Name:</label> <input id="id_name" maxlength="256" name="name" type="text" /></p>
<p><label for="id_description">Description:</label> <textarea cols="40" id="id_description" name="description" rows="10">
</textarea></p>
            <hr/>

            <br />
            <h1>Image Form</h1>
            <div id="image_formset">
                <h3>Image 1</h3>
                <label for="image_name_1">Name:</label>
                <input id="image_name_1" maxlength="256" name="image_name_1" type="text" />
                <label for="image_description_1">Description:</label>
                <textarea id="image_description_1" name="image_description_1" rows="7"></textarea>
                <label for="image_file_one">Image file:</label>
                <input type="file" id="image_file_one" name="image_file_one" title="image"/>
                <hr/>
                <h3>Image 2</h3>
                <label for="image_name_2">Name:</label>
                <input id="image_name_2" maxlength="256" name="image_name_2" type="text" />
                <label for="image_description_2">Description:</label>
                <textarea id="image_description_2" name="image_description_2" rows="7"></textarea>
                <label for="image_file_two">Image file:</label>
                <input type="file" id="image_file_two" name="image_file_two" title="image"/>
                <hr/>
                <h3>Image 3</h3>
                <label for="image_name_3">Name:</label>
                <input id="image_name_3" maxlength="256" name="image_name_3" type="text" />
                <label for="image_description_3">Description:</label>
                <textarea id="image_description_3" name="image_description_3" rows="7"></textarea>
                <label for="image_file_three">Image file:</label>
                <input type="file" id="image_file_three" name="image_file_three" title="image"/>
                <hr/>
                <h3>Image 4</h3>
                <label for="image_name_4">Name:</label>
                <input id="image_name_4" maxlength="256" name="image_name_4" type="text" />
                <label for="image_description_4">Description:</label>
                <textarea id="image_description_4" name="image_description_4" rows="7"></textarea>
                <label for="image_file_four">Image file:</label>
                <input type="file" id="image_file_four" name="image_file_four" title="image"/>
                <hr/>
                <h3>Image 5</h3>
                <label for="image_name_5">Name:</label>
                <input id="image_name_5" maxlength="256" name="image_name_5" type="text" />
                <label for="image_description_5">Description:</label>
                <textarea id="image_description_5" name="image_description_5" rows="7"></textarea>
                <label for="image_file_five">Image file:</label>
                <input type="file" id="image_file_five" name="image_file_five" title="image"/>
                <hr/>
            </div>
            <div><input type="submit" value="Submit"/></div>
        </form>
```

**Error Log:**

```
MultiValueDictKeyError at /gallery/new/

"'image_file_one'"

Request Method:     POST
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/gallery/new/
Django Version:     1.6.5
Exception Type:     MultiValueDictKeyError
Exception Value:    

"'image_file_one'"

Exception Location:     /opt/Documents/project_name/coolsite/projects/cms/django/utils/datastructures.py in __getitem__, line 301
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version:     2.7.6
Python Path:    

['lib',
 '/opt/Documents/project_name/coolsite/projects/cms',
 '/opt/Documents/project_name/coolsite/projects/cms/djangoappengine/lib',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.1.1',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/antlr3',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/fancy_urllib',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/ipaddr',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/yaml-3.10',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/rsa',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/pyasn1',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/pyasn1_modules',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/simplejson',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/endpoints-1.0',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/jinja2-2.6',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/protorpc-1.0',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/PyAMF-0.6.1',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/markupsafe-0.15',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webob-1.2.3',
 '/Applications/GoogleAppEngineLauncher.app/Contents/Resources/GoogleAppEngine-default.bundle/Contents/Resources/google_appengine/lib/webapp2-2.5.2',
 'lib',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python27.zip',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-darwin',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/plat-mac/lib-scriptpackages',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python/PyObjC',
 '/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages']

Server time:    Thu, 11 Dec 2014 20:39:49 +0000
```

Comment: You are most likely hitting one of the Google App Engine limits, is it an option to upload them using separate threads instead? Here's a bunch of scripts that handle everything for you on the client side: http://designscrazed.org/html5-jquery-file-upload-scripts/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works after increasing the following value at settings.py

```
FILE_UPLOAD_MAX_MEMORY_SIZE = 35000000
```

Apparently this value is for the combined size of all files in the POST. 
Eg: It allows 5 files with a max size of 7 MB each. Or 4 files 8.75 MB each, and so on.

Documentation: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/settings/